# Creation rules with kibana alerting

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, alerts

We are trying to start to use the rules and connectors of kibana to alert us when we have a high temperature. We already ingest the data from csvs files with logstash.

The problem is that we can choose the index to create the rule with elasticsearch query or index threshold but kibana just let us choose a @timestamp field, when we have a lot of more fields already ingested.

Someone know something about this?

Thanks.